# Exponential function given two points

Tags: functions, exponential-function, graphing-functions

I am trying to find an exponential function satisfying two points (having base "exp"). After some search, I couldn't find something relative (the most relevant was that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_LQdGKw9sNs video, but it wasn't really helpful). To be more specific, I have the points (1, 20), (4, 200) for which I am trying to find a function.

Thank you

Comment: you want base $e$? Or you are looking for the $a$ in $f(x)=a^x$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exponential functions have the formula
$$f(x)=a^{x-h}+k$$

Since you base is $e$, this then translates to

$$f(x)=e^{x-h}+k$$

You have two points then.  So plug them both in to get

$$20=e^{1-h}+k$$
$$200=e^{4-h}+k$$

Thus

$$20-e^{1-h}=200-e^{4-h}$$

$$e^{-h}(e^4-e)=180$$
$$e^{-h}=\frac{180}{e(e^3-1)}$$
$$-h=\ln{\frac{180}{e(e^3-1)}}$$
$$h=-\ln{\frac{180}{e(e^3-1)}}=\ln{\frac{e(e^3-1)}{180}}\approx. -1.244026$$

Now, $$20=e^{1-\ln\frac{e(e^3-1)}{180}}+k$$
$$20=\frac{e}{e^{\ln\frac{e(e^3-1)}{180}}}+k$$
$$20=\frac{180}{e^3-1}+k$$
so
$$k=20-\frac{180}{e^3-1}\approx 10.56877$$

From wolframalpha.com, with approximations for the $h$ and $k$ yields the result

[image]

Comment: I am trying to do the same for the points (0, 200), (20, 10000), but the relative plot I made after that I think it is wrong. To be more specific:

f(x) = e^(x-h)+k
200 = e^(-h) + k
10000 = e^(20-h) + k

200 - e^(-h) = 10000 - e^(20-h)

e^(20-h) - e^(-h) = 9800

e^(-h) = 9800/(e^20 - 1)

-h = ln (9800/(e^20)-1)

h = - ln(9800/(e^20)-1) = ln ((e^20)-1/9800) ~= 49506. 65249

Concerning the k,

k = 200 - e^(-h) = 200 - e^(-49506.65249) ~= 200

Do you find any error?

Comment: I will check it in the morning.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven I wrote a couple of functions in Javascript to do what you've done here. I got them to return the right values for my two x inputs. But when I plug in other x values between those two test points, I just get a straight line, not an exponential curve. Should I not expect a curve?

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven I think this is what you did. It just gives me linear increments for h, and the k equation also gives me linear increments: $h = ln(\frac{e(e^{x - x_{1}}))}{y_{2}-y_{1}})$

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven Sorry, I get it now: plot both the h and k, now I get a nice curve. Thanks so much for this answer!