# how to make exponential function that matches with linear one at a specific (x,y)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I want to make an exponential function that also starts at (0,0) and hits (5,5). The exponent should be a variable and so should the end point. 
I can only perform any transformation on the line as long as it "fits", e.g. has the same start/end point.

Difference between this and the other question:

I would also like to know if there is a way that I can introduce a variable in here so that the start/end points are maintained, but the exponent is more or less gradual/even vs late/sudden.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exponential function given two points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102645/exponential-function-given-two-points)

Answer (score 1):

$e^{\frac{x}{a}}-1$ passes over (0,0)

Now you want that function to cross as well at given $(x_0, f(x_0))$ so

$e^{\frac{x_0}{a}}-1 = f(x_0)$

Applying $\log$ to both sides:

$\log{(e^{\frac{x_0}{a}})} = \log{(f(x_0) +1)}$

Which makes:

$\frac{x_0}{a} = \log{(f(x_0) +1)}$

So $a=\frac{x_0}{log{(f(x_0) +1)}}$

This is generic, if you want it to pass over (5,5) just make $x_0=5$ and $f(x_0)=5$

Comment: thank you. Is there a way to add another variable in this, so that the curve upward can be more gradual/even or more late/sudden but still have the same start/end?

Comment: A general exponential function is 

$$\mathrm f(x) = a + b\mathrm c^{dx+e}$$

Answer (score 1):

An exponential graph is given by $y=a^x$, where $a>0$, $a \neq 1$ is constant.

We can perform translations and dilations on this graph to give

$$y = p+q(a^{rx+s})$$

where $p,q,r,s$ are constants.

If you want $(x,y)=(0,0)$ to lie on this curve, then you need $0 = p+q(a^s)$.

If you want $(x,y) = (5,5)$ to lie on this curve, then you need $5= p+q(a^{5r+s})$

Assuming that $a>0$, $a \neq 1$ is constant, you have two equations in four unknowns $p,q,r,s$.

This suggests that you may have as many as two degrees of freedom.

For my degrees of freedom, let me choose $s=0$ and $q=1$:
$$y = p+ a^{rx}$$

If the curve passes through $(x,y)=(0,0)$, then $0=p+a^0  \implies p = -1$.

If the curve also passes through $(x,y) = (5,5)$ then $5=-1+a^{5r} 
\implies r=\frac{1}{5}\log_a(6)$.

$$y=-1+a^{x\log_a(6)/5}$$

There are many other possible solutions. It depends how you use/spend your two degrees of freedom. If you let us choose $a$, then there are three degrees of freedom.

Comment: The only restriction I want is that the start and end points are the same for all of them. I am writing this into code so anything that can be a variable I want to be.

Comment: @maxpleaner Well, then you have a three parameter family of exponential curves that pass through $(0,0)$ and $(5,5)$. This is impossible to animate (time is only one dimension). Please remember to up-vote useful answers.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I plugged this into wolfram alpha (it is the last equation you show) and the y-intercept is 1 not zero. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+y+%3D+2%5E(+(x)+(log%5B2,+5%5D)+%2F+5+)

Comment: @maxpleaner Thanks for that. There was a "typo" in my answer. Well, to be honest, I made the mistake of thinking that $a^0 = 0$. I've fixed it now, but I fell ashamed.

Comment: See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x+from+0+to+5)+graph+y+%3D+-1+%2B+10%5E(+(x)+(log%5B10,+6%5D)+%2F+5+)) for a wolframalpha plot of this equation for A=10. Yet when I try different values of A, the graph for x between 0 and 5 looks the same. How can I have some variation?

Comment: Upon closer inspection, the value of $a$ is irrelevant:

$$a^{x\log_a(6)/5)} = \left(a^{\log_a(6)}\right)^{x/5} = 6^{x/5}$$